# Compare row 1 and row 2 ( and so on) in same dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working on a journal entry database I want to check if row 1 and 2, then row 2 and 3,(and so on) have the same amounts based on same account no. (to check debit credit postings, please note, i have already sorted the data based on absolute function on amounts)
Please find attached the example data that i working on
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNxfg.png)

Can i do this without using a for loop?

If yes then how? and if not then what should be the ideal for loop for this?
included below is the for loop i tried which didn't work

```
for i, j in range(sales_acc):
    if sales_acc["Amount LC"][i]==sales_acc["Amount LC"][j] & sales_acc["ACCOUNTNUMBER"][i]==sales_acc["ACCOUNTNUMBER"][j]:
        Elimination.append(i)
        Elimination.append(j)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Please, could you include your sample as a text and not as an image?

Comment: Please provide an [mre], at the bare minimum copyable input data, the expected output and what you already tried. To easily get the input data, you can use somthing like this: `df.iloc[:10].to_dict()` and post the result here. Whre df is your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do

```
for i, j in range(sales_acc):
```

First, `range()` returns a single integer at each iteration, so you cannot assign it to two variables.

Second, you probably wanted to write `range(len(sales_acc))`

Third, are you indexing correctly? Shouldn't it be `sales_acc[i]["Amount LC"]`

Fourth, if it worked, look at what would happen if you had 3 consecutive identical rows: you would tag the second one for elimination twice.

Anyhow you don't need two variables - just use `i` and `i+1` to check the current entry and the next one.

Re: not using a for loop, there may be ways to not *explicitly* use it, but a loop will always be executed, since this is exactly what you are doing: looping on your data :)